# How to connect presto using logstash to fetch data from Cassandra DB

Tags: logstash-jdbc

I am trying to connect presto using logstash to pull data from Cassandra DB. I am looking for presto-cassandra connectivity using logstash.
I tried few jdbc drivers but it could not create the connectivity.

Could you please let us know if connection with Presto is possible? If yes, could you please help with correct JDBC driver and online resources.